# "Syntax Error on token expected" in Java

Tags: java, html, syntax-error

```
package com.html;

import java.io.File;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class Link {

File htmlTemplateFile = new File("email-template.html");
String htmlString = FileUtils.readFileToString(htmlTemplateFile,"UTF-8");
String Requestor = "Eva Schaubs";
String Transaction_ID = "FD_20160817094502";
String TicketNumber1 ="0034317479";
String TicketNumber2 ="0034317480";
String Description1 ="Request for Desktop";
String Description2 ="Request for New Phone";
String Asset_Name1 ="Desktop PC";
String Asset_Name2 ="Phone";
String Classification1 ="PROCUREMENT_NEW";
String Classification2 ="NEW/CREATION";
String Group1 ="NAFTA_MBUSA_Asset_Mgm";
String Group2 ="NAFTA_DC_TELEPHONY";
String Status1 ="ACTIVE";
String Status2 ="ACTIVE";
htmlString = htmlString.replace("$Requestor", Requestor);
htmlString = htmlString.replace("$Transaction_ID", Transaction_ID);
htmlString = htmlString.replace("$TicketNumber1", TicketNumber1);
htmlString = htmlString.replace("$TicketNumber2", TicketNumber2);
htmlString = htmlString.replace("$Description1", Description1);
htmlString = htmlString.replace("$Description2", Description2);
htmlString = htmlString.replace("$Asset_Name1", Asset_Name1);
htmlString = htmlString.replace("$Asset_Name2", Asset_Name2);
htmlString = htmlString.replace("$Classification1", Classification1);
htmlString = htmlString.replace("$Classification2", Classification2);
htmlString = htmlString.replace("$Group1", Group1);
htmlString = htmlString.replace("$Group2", Group2);
htmlString = htmlString.replace("$Status1", Status1);
htmlString = htmlString.replace("$Status2", Status2);

File newHtmlFile = new File("path/new.html");
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(newHtmlFile, htmlString);

}
```

This throws an error:

> asking for closing of token.. at line **"String Status2"**

I don't know what silly mistake I made.

Comment: You're referencing and re-assigning a variable neither within a method, constructor or  instance / static block.

Comment: Read about naming conventions: [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions)

Comment: Hint: A) read those compiler messages carefully; and have a close look at the lines they call out. Typically, that is really all you need to solve the puzzle B) if you cant solve it; then post the error message here; and include information which line the error message applies to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is very simply:

If you want to have a sequence of statements directly within a class, you need a block around that, like:

```
class SomeClass {
  String someField;
  {
    someField = "foo";
    someField = "ah, better make me bar";
  }
```

But of course: this is would be very bad practice. Instead, you should have various methods that do such work; maybe one called "readHtmlTemplate()"; and another one "replacePatternsInHtml()" and so on.

Your style of coding is like one huge "no-go".

Comment: Your question goes beyond what can be easily explained here. I would suggest: look out for more experienced programmers around you, and have them review your code. Then, read books, such as "Clean code" or "Agile principles" by Robert Martin. You will not understand them the first time. So read them; practice; and read them again. Then: repeat. Learning never ends. For now: as said: have a look at your code and try to identify the **different responsibilities** that are in there (like: reading a file; replacing strings; and so on). These are good candidates to become methods.

Comment: Thank you @GhostCat